Darktheme is not applied although its selected on settings
I am using ubuntu 24.04 dark theme selection does not effect anything on the system. The solutions I've tried so far:
1.) Cleared the cache.
2.)1479  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme prefer-dark
   1480  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-dark
   1481  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark

3.) gtk3.0 and gtk4.0 .ini files configured as shown below.
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1

4.) I reinstalled gnome desktop environment via terminal, rebooted and nothing changed. I am using a nvidia graphics card, dark theme and settings are working in wayland however, when I switch to x11 environment it does not work anymore although it was previously working. I want to learn the solution and causes for this problem.
